# How can I make this spherical gradient in an OpenGL fragment shader?

Tags: c++, opengl, shader

I'm new to OpenGL. I'd like my background to look as if the player is inside the sphere pictured below. White as the player looks up, black as the player looks down, and a gradient along the way.

I tried enclosing the camera in a diamond shaped prism and assigning white to the top vertex, gray to middles, and black to the bottom. But the seams of the triangles are very apparent, which I don't totally understand why. It seems overkill to make more vertices to better approximate a sphere. I feel like I should be able to do this all in the fragment shader, but don't know enough to implement it. I can pass the camera's y direction [-1,1] as a uniform to the shader.

How can I implement this?

[image: Sphere Gradient]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution A: Add more triangles. This way they will be less noticeable. Modern GPUs can render 3 or 3000 triangles just as easily in your case.

Solution B: Apply a texture with a gradient to your "diamond shaped prism"

Solution C: Write a custom fragment shader which will assign pixel color depending on vertical location

Comment: For solution A: I currently don't have any normals. Does it make sense to add normals without adding a light source? Do I need a light source from a point?

Comment: For solution C: I'd like to do this, but I'm not quite sure how to calculate it.

Comment: @acerd: A - I will fix answer now. C - you can pass uniform with low/high range of the object.

Comment: For C: Are you talking about using the diamond shaped prism and assigning colors based on the fragments height with relation to the triangle, or are you talking about covering the whole screen with two triangles whose pixels are colored with relation to their distance from the min or max? If you're talking about the second, I understand how I'd get the color from the camera's y direction with relation to the min or max, but that would just be the color for the center of the screen. What about the pixels at the top of the screen?

Comment: What would be the projected y value of the pixels at the top of the screen?

Comment: @acerd: Please post a screen of what you have got working wrongly.

Answer (score 0):

why not use y coordinate as color intensity instead of texture...

- in Players coordinate system it looks like this:
- [image: overview]
- so let `(0,0,0)` be the players position (center of sphere)
- let `r` be the radius of sphere
- So in Fragment shader compute the color like this:

  ```
  float i=0.5f+(0.5f*y/r);
  if (i>1.0f) i=1.0f; // white for out of sphere fragments
  if (i<0.0f) i=1.0f; // here you could have 0.0 if triangles are outer not inner
  vec3 col; col=vec3(i,i,i);
  ```
- do not forget that tis works only localy in Players coordinate system

Now how to get rid of the triangulation artifacts?

- normalize the fragment coordinates before applying the above
- so let `vec3 p` be the rendered fragment position in player coordinate system
- you are rendering surface of the sphere so the distance from `(0,0,0)` should be `r`
- so normalize the `p` to it
- `p.xyz*=r/length(p);`
- and now use `p.y`